# Merge XML Dataset Datatables into one Datatable

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, ssis

I need to parse an XML document using C# to get the data into a database.

Currently, I am using SSIS and this C# code to read the document into a dataset:

```
var xmlString = File.ReadAllText(Variables.filepath);
var stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
var dsSet = new DataSet();
dsSet.ReadXml(stringReader);
```

This reads the XML perfectly, but it breaks it up into multiple tables with relationships. Is there a way to combine all the datatables into one table so I can get all into a SQL table?

XML Example:

[image: XML]

Relationship Example:

[image: Relationship]

Comment: Can you show how it is broken up?

Comment: Unfortunately, the data itself is sensitive. However, the hardware inventory data in this document explains it: http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/m/white_papers/20270305

Comment: Well you can censor the data however you see fit, need a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @hellyale Do the pictures I provided help?

Comment: The DataSet ReadXml method only works with limited number of descendants.  The method uses the root tag as the dataset name.  Next level tags the datatable names.  The next level tag is the column names.  The fourth level tag is the row data.  Once you get more than 4 levels of tags the method creates fragmented tables that cannot easily be recombined.  So I normally manually write code the uses xml linq to put results into a single datatable that is usable.  If you post the text version of the sample xml I can do in a few minutes.  Very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Message Id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Protocol Version", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name Instance URL", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Classname", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Key Binding", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Key Value", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Property Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Display Value", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement cim = doc.Root;
            XElement message = cim.Element("MESSAGE");
            List<XElement> values = message.Descendants("VALUE.NAMEDINSTANCE").ToList();


            string messageId = (string)message.Attribute("ID");
            string version = (string)message.Attribute("PROTOCOLVERSION");

            foreach (XElement value in values)
            {
                string url = value.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("fo").NamespaceName;

                XElement instanceName = value.Element("INSTANCENAME");
                string classname = (string)instanceName.Attribute("CLASSNAME");
                string binding = (string)instanceName.Element("KEYBINDING").Attribute("NAME");
                string key = (string)instanceName.Descendants("KEYVALUE").FirstOrDefault();
                XElement instance = value.Element("INSTANCE");
                foreach (XElement valueArray in instance.Descendants("VALUE.ARRAY"))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        messageId,
                        version,
                        url,
                        classname,
                        binding,
                        key,
                        (string)valueArray.Attribute("NAME"),
                        (string)valueArray.Element("VALUE"),
                        (string)valueArray.Element("DisplayValue")
                    });
                }
                foreach (XElement property in instance.Elements("PROPERTY"))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        messageId,
                        version,
                        url,
                        classname,
                        binding,
                        key,
                        (string)property.Attribute("NAME"),
                        (string)property.Element("VALUE"),
                        (string)property.Element("DisplayValue")
                    });

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

xml that I used to test

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CIM CIMVERSION="2.0" DTDVERSION="2.0">
  <MESSAGE ID="4711" PROTOCOLVERSION="1.0">
    <SIMPLEREQ>
      <VALUE.NAMEDINSTANCE xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <INSTANCENAME CLASSNAME="DCIM_ControllerView">
          <KEYBINDING NAME="InstanceID">
            <KEYVALUE VALUETYPE="string">RAID.Slot.1-1</KEYVALUE>
          </KEYBINDING>
        </INSTANCENAME>
        <INSTANCE CLASSNAME="DCIM_ControllerView">
          <PROPERTY NAME="DriverVersion" TYPE="string">
            <DisplayValue/>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="KeyID" TYPE="string">
            <DisplayValue/>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="SASAddress" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>5782BCB00C577600</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>5782BCB00C577600</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="ProductName" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>PERC H310 Adapter</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>
              PERC
              H310 Adapter
            </DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="DeviceCardSlotType" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>PCI Express x8</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>
              PCI Express
              x8
            </DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="DeviceCardManufacturer" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>DELL</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>DELL</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="PCISubDeviceID" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>1F4E</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>1F4E</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="PCIDeviceID" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>73</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>73</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="PCISubVendorID" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>1028</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>1028</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="PCIVendorID" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>1000</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>1000</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="Function" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>0</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>0</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="Device" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>0</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>0</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="Bus" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>1</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>1</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="ControllerFirmwareVersion" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>20.10.1-0066</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>
              20.10.1-
              0066
            </DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
        </INSTANCE>
      </VALUE.NAMEDINSTANCE>
      <VALUE.NAMEDINSTANCE xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <INSTANCENAME CLASSNAME="DCIM_ControllerView">
          <KEYBINDING NAME="InstanceID">
            <KEYVALUE VALUETYPE="string">RAID.Slot.1-1</KEYVALUE>
          </KEYBINDING>
        </INSTANCENAME>
        <INSTANCE CLASSNAME="DCIM_ControllerView">
          <PROPERTY NAME="DriverVersion" TYPE="string">
            <DisplayValue/>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="KeyID" TYPE="string">
            <DisplayValue/>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="SASAddress" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>5782BCB00C577600</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>5782BCB00C577600</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="ProductName" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>PERC H310 Adapter</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>
              PERC
              H310 Adapter
            </DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="DeviceCardSlotType" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>PCI Express x8</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>
              PCI Express
              x8
            </DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="DeviceCardManufacturer" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>DELL</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>DELL</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="PCISubDeviceID" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>1F4E</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>1F4E</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="PCIDeviceID" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>73</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>73</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="PCISubVendorID" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>1028</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>1028</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="PCIVendorID" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>1000</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>1000</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="Function" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>0</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>0</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="Device" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>0</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>0</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="Bus" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>1</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>1</DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="ControllerFirmwareVersion" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>20.10.1-0066</VALUE>
            <DisplayValue>
              20.10.1-
              0066
            </DisplayValue>
          </PROPERTY>
        </INSTANCE>
      </VALUE.NAMEDINSTANCE>

    </SIMPLEREQ>
  </MESSAGE>
</CIM>
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is going on here? Also when I paste in the code it does not recognize XDocument and XElement

Comment: You need to add at top of module : using System.Xml.Linq;  I made a datatable with 9 columns.  Then created a new row in table for each occurrence of the Element "Property" using dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {...}.  The data is added to the row in the same order as the columns are defined.

Comment: I'm getting: System.Xml.Linq.XElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix(...) returned null.     What is "fo" for?

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like my example XML doesn't match up with my actual one exactly. Thank you for the code.

Comment: fo is the prefix name of a namespace.  You can eliminate any columns you do no need.  i just parsed everything so you could see a sample of how to get all the elements.

Comment: What if I have multiple instances I need to look through with more sets of properties? I tired adding another for each loop outside the one you had posted, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Which is the 2nd element you are looping on. I will update the code.  If you have multiple instances then 1) : foreach(XElement instance in instanceName.Elements("INSTANCE")) 2) : foreach(XElement property in instance.Elements("PROPERTY"))

Comment: Everything from VALUE.NAMEDINSTANCE and below I have multiples of. I apologize since I am unfamiliar of XML structure. It is either for each <VALUE.NAMEDINSTANCE> or INSTANCE

Comment: Still getting the same results as before. Isn't there a way for me to just use my original code, and untangle all the relationships into a single data table? It seems like a much easier solution but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: There may be something else wrong.  I added the xml I used to test where I copied the first instance so there are two instances.  See if it matches your xml file.

Comment: It looks like it matches, although the spacing is slightly different from mine. I'm assuming there isn't a way to do it by just merging/joining the relationships?

Comment: Would be more complicated.  Trying to keep code simple.  Besides I don't think you would get any different results than you are getting now.  Must be a something different about the code.  What I would do is following from VS menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then paste your xml file into view.  There are plus/minus signs were you can open and close sections of the xml.  See if you can find difference between first Instance and the other instances.

Comment: Why would it be more complicated than manually defining columns and looping through them? If the relationships are defined on import why can I just stitch them together afterwards?

Comment: Until we find the differences merging will not work.  For merging to work you need the correct element names. Right now it is not finding the correct name.

Comment: I went to the schema in the pdf document and found the issue.  Updated the code.