# How to bind user-control or custom-control to XML/data table?

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, bind, windows-forms-designer

I have no idea how to make my own-control/custom-control bindable to XML or even DataTable.
I need to divide data from the view.
for example, I use devComponent advTreeView and I made some custom columns and extra data in each node, and I want to make them bindable.
so I could bind the DataTable/XML to the tree and finally, I have all I need in the dataSource.
if userControl and customControl are different in behavior (I doubt it) I need both.
thank you.

ps: c#-WindowsForms and I need a general solution, please.

Comment: See following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076543/merge-xml-dataset-datatables-into-one-datatable/49083136#49083136

Comment: @jdweng I know how to work with XML and DataTable, sorry, but I'm afraid you are not in the picture.

Comment: So what is so hard about binding.  You just need to link from TreeView to an object.

Comment: @jdweng actually I don't know how binding works. if I wanted to implement this functionality I may have many solutions, but I want to do the one that everybody does. I mean like DataGridView that binds to a DataTable, I don't know how. is it related to BindableAttribute?

Comment: With a DGV usually you use a DataTable DataSource instead of a bind,  It is really just a pointer, but in c# we do not use pointers we just do links.  So you can just link the TreeView to an XElement,  Then is you want to view you need to get the value of the XElement or cast to a string.

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean by 'link'? just keeping a reference from an element? when I say bind I mean for example when you edit the TreeNode label, automatically effects on the value in XML and vice versa.

Comment: Why can't you bind to an XElement?  It is the same as binding to a DataRow.  Both point to objects and then you need to get value(s) from object.

Comment: could you bring a piece of code that I can set it as the answer?@jdweng